# Redirect from webform to MVC ..getting errors

Tags: redirect, model-view-controller, webforms

I am trying out MVC in existing MVC application . I want to do redirect from webform which is in 'Folder1' to MVC Homecontroller which is in Controllers folder ,same level as Folder1.
I tried this ,its The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

```
UrlHelper urlHelp = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);   
Response.Redirect(urlHelp.Action("About", "Home"), false);
```

and even tried with

```
Response.Redirect(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath + "Home/Index");
```

even tried this

```
UrlHelper urlHelp = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);           
Response.Redirect(urlHelp.Action("Index", "Home",new { area = string.Empty }),false);
```

didn`t work out ..Anybody have idea?

Comment: Would be helpful to see the controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
UrlHelper urlHelp = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(System.UriPartial.Authority) + urlHelp.Action("About", "Home"), false);
```

Comment: I am getting this error.    The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

Comment: I changed my answer. Please try it out.

Comment: hmm. i must be missing something here. If you set a string up and equal it to that path what is the URL you get at runtime? trade out response.redirect for string test =... If the string you get doesn't look like the URL you need play with that first part until it does.